# Syntax for using a struct as input in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm trying to separate a program out into a few pieces (as in, have the function written separately rather in the same file). The function I'm using outputs an array of structs and when I have everything together in the one file, it runs fine. I'm wondering how to call this struct function properly though from my main in a separate file. At the moment, I have this:

```
void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct boat_params *values);

int main () {

double L1, L2, Lavg, H;
struct boat_params values[211]; 

L1 = 17.6; 
L2 = 3; 
Lavg = 4;
H = 4.5;

submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H, values);

unsigned char i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 90; ++i) {
    printf("V = %lf\nUc = %lf\nVc = %lf\n", values[i].V, values[i].Uc, values[i].Vc);
}



return 0;

}
```

The submerged_volume function starts like this: 
    void submerged_volume(double L1, double L2, double Lavg, double H, struct boat_params *results)

**Note** - When the main is in the same file, it works. At the moment, the errors I'm getting with the set up of having them in separate files are:

```
friction_equilibrium.c:12:26: error: array has incomplete element type 'struct boat_params'
struct boat_params values[211]; 
                         ^
friction_equilibrium.c:12:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct boat_params'
struct boat_params values[211]; 
       ^
friction_equilibrium.c:19:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'submerged_volume' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
submerged_volume(L1, L2, Lavg, H, values);
```

I hope this is explained ok!! Any ideas on what these errors mean and how to fix them? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're not showing the definition of `struct boat_params`. in your code. I suspect you need to learn how to use header files and `#include` directive.

Comment: Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char**argv)`.  If your book suggests `int main()`, it is either a book for `C++` or very old and should be treated with suspicion.

Comment: I think I've seen almost the same question before on SO a couple of weeks ago...

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that `struct boat_params` have not been defined yet. You need define it before you use it.

This is commonly done by using *header files*, that you `#include` when needed. One typically puts structure definition and function prototypes in the header file.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the route suggested (I do have a book that I'm following as well). However, I was wondering if this was the only way to do this as I've defined functions not in the same file before not using header files.

Comment: The C compiler will assume that a function for which it has not seen a declaration returns int and takes a variable number of arguments.  However, failing to declare a function is considered bad practice and is only supported for backwards compatibility.  You should provide a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Put the definition of `struct boat_params` and a declaration of `submerged_volume()` in a header file.  Include that file in both `main.c` and `submerged_volume.c`.  Compile and link separately:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c submerged_volume.c
gcc main.o submerged_volume.o -o main
```